# Using Async/Await to Control Order of Operations

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to come up with a way to ensure that a certain action has completed before another function is fired. In my code I fire off an API request to update data, and then I calculate some other value based on the result of that first request.

However, what I sometimes ran into was that the first request wouldn't complete prior to the second function firing, and so the data would end up corrupted and out of sync. I've been temporarily handling this with a timeout on the second function. However, I'd like to use async/await instead as it's clearly the better (and assured) way to handle something like this -- as it's never good to assume a timeout will work, when it may not.

This is what I currently have:

```
private async moveRecord(stage) {
    if (!this.customer || !this.selectedService) return;
    let targetService = this.selectedService.service;
    let staffStarted = await this.userAccessService.getTargetId();

    this.clientMoveService.moveClientRecord(this.client._id, category, targetService, staffStarted);

    setTimeout(() =>
    {
        this.getNextStageOperation();
    }, 1000);
}
```

How can I adjust this code to use async/await to only fire `this.getNextOperation` once the first request `this.clientMoveService.moveClientRecord()` has completed?

Can I simply do this?

```
private async moveRecord(stage) {
    if (!this.customer || !this.selectedService) return;
    let targetService = this.selectedService.service;
    let staffStarted = await this.userAccessService.getTargetId();

    await this.clientMoveService.moveClientRecord(this.client._id, category, targetService, staffStarted);

    this.getNextStageOperation();
}
```

For further clarity, `moveClientRecord()` is a request that goes out over sockets and looks like this:

```
public moveClientRecord(clientId: string, category: string, service: string, staffStarted: string)
{
    let args = { id: clientId, category: category, service: service, staff: staffStarted };
    console.log('args: ', args);

    API.service.cast({
        eventName: `clients.updateStatus`,
        args: args,
        listener: function (data)
        {
            // Ignore if socket disconnects
            if (data === 'disconnect' || data === 'error') return;

            // Return true to stop event listener
            return true;

        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

Comment: What does `moveClientRecord` return?

Comment: It updates data in the backend, which is then used as part of the criteria to return the data asked for with `getNextStageOperation`. In other words, the first operation must complete before the second one is kicked off.

Comment: you should await clientMoveService

Comment: How does one "ensure" `moveClientRecord()` is returning a promise?

Comment: @jack.the.ripper, I added code above. Is that sufficient? Or is something else required?

Comment: @Muirik Well, you haven't posted the `moveClientRecord` code, so we can't be specific, but presumably you have access to the that code, yes? So look at what it's returning. If it's returning the result of an asynchronous call that returns a promise, you're good. If not, you should wrap the return value in `Promise.resolve` or `Promise.reject` (depending on if the value represents success or failure).

Comment: This is good, I'm getting closer here. Please define how one knows for certain that " it's returning the result of an asynchronous call". `moveClientRecord()` triggers a call to the API to update data, and it takes (obviously) some time to complete. Does that define it as asynchronous?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk "*Wrapping it in `Promise.resolve`/`Promise.reject`*" is not enough. Either it synchronously returns a value and there's nothing to wait for, or you need to properly construct a promise that will resolve when the API response arrives.

Comment: @Muirik Are you using promises for making that call to the API? You should not only "trigger" it, you should also create a promise for the response.

Comment: @Bergi If it's synchronous, wrapping it in Promise.resolve / Promise.reject will still allow it to be awaited just fine. It's unnecessary, unless the function has branches which are async and branches which are not; then it's completely necessary.

Comment: @Bergi, are you saying I this kind of syntax to ensure this is a promise? `let promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});`

Comment: Just so I'm clear, using "await" only works if a call returns a promise, correct? How does one ENSURE that a call returns a promise? What syntax is needed to ensure that?

Comment: @Muirik Yes, that syntax looks good (of course, it's still waiting only for a timeout and not for your API call to finish before resolving). About "ensure", no you don't need any special syntax, you just need to `return` the promise. Make sure not to forget the `return` keyword anywhere (as often happens).

Comment: I'd still like to know how to check to see is my API calls returns a promise. How can one check that the `this.clientMoveService.moveClientRecord(this.client._id, category, targetService, staffStarted);`  returns a promise? What's the simplest way to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

It will work this way:

```
private async moveRecord(stage) {
    if (!this.customer || !this.selectedService) return;
    let targetService = this.selectedService.service;
    let staffStarted = await this.userAccessService.getTargetId();

    // must return a Promise
    await this.clientMoveService.moveClientRecord(this.client._id, 
    category, targetService, staffStarted);

    this.getNextStageOperation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this.clientMoveService.moveClientRecord returns a promise, you can just do

```
await this.clientMoveService.moveClientRecord(this.client._id, category, targetService, staffStarted);
```